# Using D3, how would one make a repeating area graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a graph with a fixed X axis (angle 0-360deg), that i would like the user to be able to pan the graph, and when it goes beyond the range, it starts repeating itself again. Any suggestions on how to make the graph repeat itself?

Simplified version of the issue:

```js
const data = [{x:0,y:10},{x:30,y:20},{x:60,y:30},{x:90,y:40},{x:120,y:30},{x:150,y:20},{x:180,y:10},{x:210,y:20},{x:240,y:30},{x:270,y:40},{x:300,y:30},{x:330,y:20},{x:360,y:10}];
const width = 600;
const height= 200;

const svg = d3.select("svg");
const range = document.getElementById("range");

svg.attr('viewBox', [0, 0, width, height]);

const altitudeScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
const azimuthScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
altitudeScale.domain([0, 100]);
azimuthScale.domain([0, 120]);

const pathElement = svg
      .append('path')
      .attr('fill', 'rgba(80,200,80,0.8)')
      .attr('stroke', 'green')
      .attr('stroke-width', 0.5)
      .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
      .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round');
      
const update = () => {
  const val = +range.value;
  pathElement.datum(data)
    .call(path =>
      path.attr(
        'd',
        d3.area()
          .x(d => azimuthScale(d.x))
          .y0(height)
          .y1(d => altitudeScale(d.y))
      ));
  azimuthScale.domain([val, 120 + val]);
}

update()
range.addEventListener("input", update);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
<input min=-360 max=720 type=range id="range">
```